# How to refer to a label in inline asm for LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, inline-assembly

I have an inline assembly instruction as follows that loads a label address into a register. The label is defined somewhere else in the code (could be defined in `asm` or as C++ label). I can access the label with GCC `asm goto` extended assembly, however LLVM does not have `asm goto` and I am wondering how can I refer to this label defined somewhere else from inside an inlined assembly instruction.

Here is the inlined asm instruction:

```
asm ("leaq MYLABEL(%rip), %rax");
```

Comment: If bleeding edge LLVM is an option, [it looks like `asm goto` might be available](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-Asm-Goto-Merged)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Indeed I want it to work with previous versions. So that is not an option for me. But that I did not know and I appreciate your comment.

Comment: You can try emitting the label in an asm block ... but that's a hack and not recommended. Instead, describe what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Let me know the emitting hack. The description is as I wrote. It is a benchmark kinda code not a real program and that is exactly what I want. The code itself is a little bit hack itself.

Comment: Have you tried `.global`?  That might work when combined with asm, but I'm not sure c++ labels are available once you leave c++.

Comment: There's no way to do this reliably without using asm goto, at least not in the general case. You might be able to access a label in another asm statement, but there's not much you can do with it. Jumping to it. for example, isn't likely to work reliably.  But even just loading its address into a register runs into problems like that compiler deciding to generate more than one instance of that second asm statement for whatever reason. You really need to describe what you're actually trying to do, because there's almost certainly a better way.